# NDK issues with Studio 3.5.2 on Ubuntu

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk, ubuntu-16.04, clang-tidy

I am new to NDK. Just upgraded to Android Studio 3.5.2, installed LLDB 3.1.4508709, NDK (Side by side) 21.0.6113669, CMake 3.6.4111459 (BTW, the interface is terrible) on Ubuntu 16.04.
Created a new Native C++ project from template.
Every time I open cpp file, there is a pink message on the top of the window:

Unable to execute Clang-Tidy: Cannot create property=Diagnostics for JavaBean=com.jetbrains.cidr.lang.daemon.clang.tidy.ClangTidyYamlLoader...

The message is too long to fit the window. It happens on Ubuntu only, on Mac the same IDE version works fine.
Everything else seems working ok - building, running/debugging on emulator. Just the message is quite annoying. Any ideas?

Comment: You should file a bug with the Android Studio project.

Comment: Same here, Windows platform

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. In fact, in every AndroidStudio release there are tons of small and not too small bugs, often regressions, like powermock does not work, etc. I already tried to file a bug with them in the past with no results. I do not think that they thoroughly test the product. Very disappointing.

Comment: This is a known issue. The clang-tidy integration in AS 3.5 is not compatible with NDK r21. It's fixed in 4.0.